# Set backgroud foreach cell based on condition google appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a range that has numeric values. I would like to set the background & font color based on greater than the cell value.

```
function createEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DD");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var rangeN = sheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues();
  var { backgrounds, fontColors } = range.getValues().reduce((o, [a]) => {
    o.backgrounds.push([a > 40 ? "red" : null]);
    o.fontColors.push([a > 40 ? "white" : null]);
    return o;
  }, { backgrounds: [], fontColors: [] });
  range.setBackgrounds(backgrounds).setFontColors(fontColors);

var { backgrounds, fontColors } = range.getValues().reduce((o, [a]) => {
    o.backgrounds.push([a > rangeN ? "red" : null]);
    o.fontColors.push([a > rangeN ? "white" : null]);
    return o;
  }, { backgrounds: [], fontColors: [] });
  range.setBackgrounds(backgrounds).setFontColors(fontColors);
}
```

When I applied this, it applied to the whole range. Also looking based on greater than other range. I will use Time DrivenTrigger to run the script.

[Expected Worksheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e2RMeCDI6UpMUXJO4UXVSaf9LKkcGcN9QTeaIKUNjsY/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your following reply,

> I have a few changes to the question. I will use the function with Time Trigger. Also need to apply the font color as white where the red background is applied.

And, your showing script is my 1st proposed script. I understood that you wanted to add a function for changing the font color as a new request. In order to achieve your 2nd request, my 1st proposed script is required to be modified to your new goal. So, how about the following modified script?

#### Sample script:

This modified script is for your 2nd question.

```js
function createEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DD");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var { backgrounds, fontColors } = range.getValues().reduce((o, [a]) => {
    o.backgrounds.push([a > 40 ? "red" : null]);
    o.fontColors.push([a > 40 ? "white" : null]);
    return o;
  }, { backgrounds: [], fontColors: [] });
  range.setBackgrounds(backgrounds).setFontColors(fontColors);
}
```

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [setBackgrounds(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor)
- [setFontColors(colors)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setfontcolorscolors)

Comment: @Stella Thank you for replying. About `but how does it work to reset the background if the cell value changed to less than 40?`, in my proposed script, when the value is less than 40 and run the script, the background color is reset. When you run this script and the background color is not reset, I have to apologize. At that time, please confirm your current script again. Or, do you want to use OnEditt rigger although I cannot confirm it in your question?

Comment: I have a few changes to the question. I will use the function with Time Trigger. Also need to apply the font color as white where the red background is applied.

Comment: @Stella Thank you for replying. From your reply, I updated my answer. Please confirm it. But, I'm worried about your 1st comment of `but how does it work to reset the background if the cell value changed to less than 40?`. My proposed script can reset the cell color and font color by the numbers. So, I cannot replicate your 1st comment. If my updated answer was not useful, I apologize for this, again.

Comment: thank you very much. Can you check one thing, it's possible in the same script with set background based on another range? The worksheet demo is updated.

Comment: @Stella Thank you for replying. I'm glad your 2nd question was resolved. About your 3rd question of `Can you check one thing, it's possible in the same script with set background based on another range? The worksheet demo is updated.`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your 3rd question. But, I would like to try to understand your 3rd question. When I could correctly understand your 3rd question, I would like to think of a solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your various questions soon.

Comment: sure, please take your time.